# When theme is NoActionbar, intent is not working in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-webview

When theme is **NoActionbar** intent is not working in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in fragment

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent)
    return true;
};
```